# Xamarin Forms app on iOS shows many leaks

Tags: xamarin, memory-leaks, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Am i missing something here ? I just finished coding an enterprise app using Xamarin forms and unfortunately just got around to memory profiling the app. I used Instruments with the leaks profile and ran the app. Just launching the app with a simple splash screen followed by a forms page with some controls shows me 10000k or so leaks after 10 seconds.

None of the leaks are from code which I am directly controlling so I have no idea how to even attempt to root cause them.

Granted my app usage does not spike and even extensive usage still leads to around a max leak of 1.6k, but there are a million other small leaks of the same nature.

Attached an image with a typical scenario of the leaks.

Any help in understanding what I am seeing here will help :)

[image: A typical run]

Comment: Your app will use memory for controls etc.   Does the memory usage keep growing or does it hit a value and stay there?

Comment: Have you tried it with blank app?  And is `Jarvis.iOS` your ios project in `Xamarin.Forms`?